# How to change the type of the entity

Tags: php, symfony

This part of my user class

```
<?php

 class User {

  /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 private $id;

/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
*/
private $firstName;

/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
*/
private $lasttName;
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Test\TravelBundle\Entity\Flight",     inversedBy="flight")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="flight", referencedColumnName="flightnumber",        nullable=true)
  * @var \Test\TravelBundle\Entity\Flight
  **/
   private $flight;

.......
/**
 * Set flight
 *
 * @param \Test\TravelBundle\Entity\Flight $flight
 * @return User
 */
public function setFlight(\Test\TravelBundle\Entity\Flight $flight = null)
{
    $this->flight = $flight;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get flight
 *
 * @return \Test\TravelBundle\Entity\Flight
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->flight;
}
```

}

This the part where i am building a formbuild

```
 public function newUser()
{


            // ID
            ->add('id', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'form.labels.id',
                'translation_domain' => 'User'))

            // Firstname
            ->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'form.labels.firstname',
                'translation_domain' => 'User'))

          // lastName
            ->add('lastname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'form.labels.lastname',
                'translation_domain' => 'User'))

            // Flight number
            ->add('flightNumber', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'form.labels.flightNumber',
                'translation_domain' => 'User'))


                ))
            // Submit button
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'form.buttons.submitUser',
                'translation_domain' => 'submit'))
```

I want to add a new user but the flight number in  the databas has varchar so if i make inter it just accept number. The flight type should be varchar

and the flight part

```
class Flight {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, name="flightnumber")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 *
 * @var string @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $id           
 * @return Flight
 */
public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: Please, add more informations in your question. Is this field the identifier of your mysql table ? Do you have an entity that represents this field ? If yes, please add the content of your entity in your question and be more explicit about what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong.

You have two entities, Flight and User.
Those two entities represents a MySQL **table** (not just a column in your user table).

Your current implementation make an User can have one or more Flight associated.
Because it represents a table, the Flight entity cannot be an integer or a varchar, it should have an identifier and other properties that represents your MySQL table.
An identifier is most often an integer with auto-increment, like already done in your User entity.

**EDIT**

A last try. in your User entity, change the following :

```
/**
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="flightnumber", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
private $flightNumber;
```

Don't forgot to do `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle:User` and `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

And change your form field to :

```
->add('flightNumber', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'form.labels.flightNumber',
    'translation_domain' => 'User'
))
```

In this way, your flightNumber is just a column in your User table that allows strings (so all alphanumeric characters).

Comment: the type is on the database varchar, if i change to text i cant save to database

Comment: A text field is corresponding to a varchar in mysql, and to a string in doctrine mapping. Also, in your question you are only talking about a form field, no database and very little informations. 
I've updated my answer according to your need.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: What is your question ? What do you have and what do you want ?

Comment: I just updated my question. I want to add new user but each of them has a flightnumber and the flightnumber on database is varchar and if i want to save it doesnt accept because its integer

Comment: Thank you very much I tried and tried it doesnt work. How you said I have two entities. The flightnumber is a varchar, that means the number could start with zero like 0232541, which doesnt accept as a integer. When i type a number with no zero it save on database.When change the type to text it doesnt accep number.

Comment: it's the number if you want to use numeric operation on the field otherwise use varchar to avoid problems.

Comment: I've updated my answer for a last try, take a look at the solution proposed at end.

Comment: I updated my user entitiy. The flightnumber in flight is not  a key. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I cant user varchar as a type thats the thing

Comment: Why do you can't change to varchar ? Look at my edit, I'am not talking about the Flight entity (I think it is useless and can be removed because you just need a flightnumber property)

Comment: So when i change like that i dont have any reference to the entity flight?

Comment: Yes. If I understand correctly, you only want a user have a flightNumber. If is it, you don't need an entity. Otherwise, you cannot add the field `flighnumber` in your formbuilder, but use `flight` instead of, which represents the whole Flight entity, which have an identifier (id auto-increment) and a `number` field representing the flightnumber (don't use `id` for this field, the id should be your identifier and no a data).

Comment: When I fill the user form, the flightnumber is not coming from the flight entity in that case right.  The flightnumber in user is the column from the entity flight. The id of the  entity flight is the flightnumber, which has the type varchar in the database.